# Load data to a combo box

Tags: java, swing

I have two combo boxes.1 is for main department and other is for sub department. I want to load all the data in Main_department table to combo box. When selecting combo box item i want to load sub_departments relevant to that selected item.

```
try {
    Conn c=new Conn();
    Statement s=c.createConn().createStatement();

    String query ="SELECT * FROM main_dep";
    ResultSet rst = s.executeQuery(query);
    DefaultComboBoxModel dc=(DefaultComboBoxModel)maindep.getModel();

    while(rst.next()){
        dc.addElement(rst.getString(2));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is how i got the main Departments. Then i wrote following code for itemStateChange event in main Department combobox.

```
 String main = maindep.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Conn c=new Conn();
          try {
                //Conn c=new Conn();
                Statement s=c.createConn().createStatement();

                String query ="SELECT Description FROM sub_dep WHERE Main_dep_ID IN (SELECT Main_Dep_Id FROM main_dep WHERE description = '"+main+"')";
                ResultSet rst = s.executeQuery(query);
                DefaultComboBoxModel dc=(DefaultComboBoxModel)subdep.getModel();

                while(rst.next()){
                    dc.addElement(rst.getString(1));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When Main Department is changed sub Departments relevant to that department is loaded to sub Department combobox. But loaded items are Still remaining when another one is selected.

How can i overcome that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But loaded items are Still remaining when another one is selected

You can use:

```
dc.removeAllElements();
```

before you start adding new elements to the model.

Answer (score 0):

This case call dependent combo-box.
You have to load data to first combo-box first then, when user select the value of that combo-box, it will cal Ajax or another technology back to server to retrieve data to second combo-box.So , that is idea.
You can see this link for reference [here](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox)